# twig dynamic variable call

Tags: php, symfony, twig, template-engine

I passed data in 3 languages to the twig template and display this data in this way:

```
{% set lang=app.request.get("lang")%}
{% for item in contests%}
    {% if lang=="fa"%}
        {{item.titlefa}}
    {% elseif lang=="en"%}
        {{item.titleen}}
    {% elseif lang=="ar"%}
        {{item.titlear}}
    {% endif%}
{% endfor%}
```

It is wirking but I must create 3 if condition for each object in "contests"
How can  i show data in this logic:

```
{% set lang=app.request.get("lang")%}
 {{item.title~lang}}
{% endfor%}
```

that can call proper method in contest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) TWIG function for call at runtime a method name, as example:

```
    {% set lang=app.request.get("lang")%}
    {% methodname = 'title'~lang %}
      {% for item in contests%}
        {{ attribute(item, methodname) }}
      {% endfor%}
```

Hope this help